# How to loop comma separated values into select statement in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to send comma separated values into a select statement where it will update values through @sql statement.
I have common table in all Databases I need to update the table column by one update statement in the procedure.

For Example : `Input Param will be ('DataBase1','Database2',....., 'Database10')`
Below is the sample procedure :

```
DELIMITER &&  
    CREATE PROCEDURE update_stmt (IN DBName varchar(100))  
    BEGIN  
    Declare DBName = @DB;

    **comma seperated values loop and placed into the @DB**
    use @DB;
    SELECT concat(update @DB.sample SET COL = 0 where ID = \'',ID,'\','; ) as stmt FROM 
      Test.Sample into @s; 
       SET @sql = @s
       PREPARE stmt from @sql;
       EXECUTE stmt;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
       
    END &&  
    DELIMITER ;
```

so that update statement will execute in each of the databases.

Comment: ```SET one_DB = SUBSTRING_INDEX(DBName, ',', 1); SET DBName = SUBSTRING(DBName FROM 2 + LENGTH(one_DB));```

Comment: @Akina can you please put the  full code and post . I'm not able execute the procedure

Comment: `use @DB;` - this will not work. Specify complete objects names, including DB name, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. I don't try to split the comma-separated string, I use it with `FIND_IN_SET()` to match schema names in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. This filters to schemas in the list that actually exist, and tables that actually exist in that schema.

Then use a cursor to loop over the matching rows, so you don't have to split any strings, which is awkward to do in a stored procedure.

I supposed that you would want to specify the id of the row to update too, so I added that to the procedure parameters.

Also notice the use of quotes when I create `@sql`. You can concatenate strings, but those must be quote-delimited like any other string literal. Variables must not be inside the quoted string. There's no feature to expand variables inside string literals in MySQL.

```
DELIMITER &&

CREATE PROCEDURE update_stmt (IN schema_name_list VARCHAR(100), IN in_id INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT false;
  DECLARE schema_name VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sample' AND FIND_IN_SET(TABLE_SCHEMA, schema_name_list);
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = true;

  SET @id = in_id;

  OPEN cur1;

  schema_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO schema_name;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE schema_loop;
    END IF;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE `', schema_name, '`.sample SET col = 0 WHERE id = ?');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @id;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;

END &&

DELIMITER ;
```

Frankly, I hardly ever use stored procedures in MySQL. The procedure language is primitive, and the tasks I see people try to do in stored procedures could be done a lot more easily in virtually every other programming language.

Comment: I need to add more other statements and the above logic  you have mentioned which is good but to my present requirement it won't suit, Will you be able to suggest anything in my existing  code

Comment: I'm going to leave my answer as-is, because it's correct for the task you have described. I'm not going to answer tasks that you have not described, because I don't have ESP.